# Changing value of parameter within a JButton ActionEvent returns error, "must be final or effectively final"

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener, actionevent

I am trying to make a function that creates a `JButton`. The button either increases or decreases an R, G, or B value(red, green, blue). The user enters a few parameters,

- the buttons parent (JPanel)
- The text on the button (String)
- The function of the button either increase or decrease (boolean)
- The color value that the user wishes to change (int)

So if the user wishes to increase green, the integer value, `userGreen` should increase by 15. However when I tried increasing it I got an error, saying:

> Local variable userRed defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final

My actual program has a lot of variables and other functions attached and attaching the whole program would be far too long, so I made the shortest example I could. This example simply counts the number of times the button is pressed and prints it to the console.

This produces the same error

> Local variable clickNumber defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final

Is it possible to change the value of a parameter within a JButton's Action Listener? And why does the variable need to be final?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class ButtonTest {
    int clickNumber = 0;
    
    public ButtonTest() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Button Test");
        frame.add(newButton(frame, "Click me", clickNumber));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JButton newButton(JFrame parent, String text, int clickNumber) {
        JButton btn = new JButton(text);
        btn.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        
        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println(clickNumber); //error here, "Local variable clickNumber defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final"
            }
        });
        clickNumber += 1; // if i remove this than the error goes away, so changing the value of the variable is somehow related
        
        parent.add(btn);
        return btn;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String laf = UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName();
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(laf);
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {}

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                new ButtonTest();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access a variable in a local class if you change it outside it. This is what JLS (Java 11, paragraph 8.1.3) says about it:

> Any local variable, formal parameter, or exception parameter used but not declared in an inner class must either be declared final or be effectively final (§4.12.4), or a compile-time error occurs where the use is attempted.

Link: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3

---

UPD: If you want a workaround though, you can try this:

```
int finalWorkaround = clickNumber; 

btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // Our finalWorkaround is effectively final here, so we can use it
        System.out.println(finalWorkaround);
    }
});
clickNumber += 1;
```

Comment: Thanks! This workaround should work. Can you explain why is an `int` array effectively final?

Comment: You do not change `finalWorkaround` in the method (you never assign to this variable) so it is effectively final.

Comment: `clickNumber` is not effectively final because you assign a value to it.

Comment: If the answer is helpful, could you please mark it as accepted?

Comment: Meant to do that earlier, sorry. Accepted!